# Fire / smoke detectors with email notifications

Tags: smoke-detectors, alarm, fire-safety, smart-home

Are there any fire / smoke detectors that can send an email notification when activated?

I don't want mobile phone notifications, only email.

It's not important if it meets any fire safety regulations as it won't be replacing my fixed fire alarm system, it's just to notify me via email when I'm out.

Comment: If it doesn't meet regulations it tends not to be made, in this particular product-space. I suppose one or more of the "smart-home" arrangements that included smoke detectors might have this ability.

Comment: ...Or it may be a matter of what central alarm monitoring service you are using, or need to start using.

Comment: i did this with an arduino and a microphone sensor module that had an adjustment dial; I mounted the mic by the alarm and tuned it to only activate when the alarm went off; nothing else in my house is that loud. the sensor talks to my home automation system (node-red) and routes it all around from there. I got a false positive from thunder once, so I filter in node-red to only activate if on for more than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look toward hobbyist-install security systems. These usually at least have a test mode in which notifications go only to you rather than the central office, and some which integrate with home automation can be configured to send events even if the security side of things is completely disabled. If one of those offers integrated smoke detectors, that would go what you want.

Alternatively, some smart speakers have a mode that listens for things that sound like fire or CO2 alarms and can send notifications. Might be worth investigating.